# How do i overlay a div onto a div with an image inside?

Tags: html, css

i am creating a home page where there is an image covering the whole screen and there will be the logo in the center of that image and a link to take the user to the actual website.

everything is working fine but my image and link just go below the image automatically and i can't find a fix.

here is my html:

```
<div id="homebackground">
    <img src="img/home.jpg" id="homebackgroundimage" alt="homebackgroundimage">
    <div id="entersite">
        <img src="img/dignanslogo.jpg" id="logohome" alt="dignans-logo"><br />
        <a href="about.html" id="entersitelink">Enter Site</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my css:

```
#homebackground{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}

#homebackgroundimage{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#entersite{
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute; z-index:-1;
}

#logohome{
    max-width:15%;
    max-height:15%;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#entersitelink{
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is only content that you want to display on the page you don't need that much code. 
You can add one container with a background image and inside him logo and link.

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("here go url for background image");
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="img/dignanslogo.jpg" id="logohome" alt="dignans-logo">
  <a href="about.html" id="entersitelink">Enter Site</a>
</div>
```

Now you don't need to mess with absolute position and z-index. Also, you need to style image and link if you are not satisfied with default style.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give background to parent div and position absolute to inner div and need to improve css...Check Now

```css
#homebackground{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    position:relative;
    background:url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
}

#homebackgroundimage{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#entersite{
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:9;
}

#logohome{
    margin:auto;
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
}

#entersitelink{
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="homebackground">
    <div id="entersite">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2017/hirotugu-akaikes-90th-birthday-5767291382792192-l.png" id="logohome" alt="dignans-logo"><br />
        <a href="about.html" id="entersitelink">Enter Site</a>
    </div>
</div>
```